# How to disable jndi debug logs in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

How to disable the below debug logs in spring boot?
These logs appear whenever health check request is made to the application.

I've tried setting the logger level to info for these packages "org.springframework.jndi" and "javax.naming" in our log configuration file, but the above lines still appear whenever health check request is made.

```
[DEBUG] jndi - InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext()
[DEBUG] jndi - Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot@756a5bed
[DEBUG] jndi - Looking up name="comp/env/endpoints.enabled"
[DEBUG] jndi - Trying thread context classloader
[DEBUG] jndi - Looking up name="env/endpoints.enabled"
[DEBUG] jndi - InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext()
[DEBUG] jndi - Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot@6a85ff9f
[DEBUG] jndi - Looking up name="endpoints.enabled"
[DEBUG] jndi - InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext()
[DEBUG] jndi - Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot@293101e3
[DEBUG] jndi - Looking up name="comp/env/endpoints.health.sensitive"
[DEBUG] jndi - Trying thread context classloader
[DEBUG] jndi - Looking up name="env/endpoints.health.sensitive"
[DEBUG] jndi - InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext()
[DEBUG] jndi - Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot@235a3b05
[DEBUG] jndi - Looking up name="endpoints.health.sensitive"
[DEBUG] jndi - InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext()
[DEBUG] jndi - Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot@439cc794
[DEBUG] jndi - Looking up name="comp/env/endpoints.health.sensitive"
[DEBUG] jndi - Trying thread context classloader
[DEBUG] jndi - Looking up name="env/endpoints.health.sensitive"
[DEBUG] jndi - InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext()
[DEBUG] jndi - Created initial context delegate for local namespace:org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot@221fa466
[DEBUG] jndi - Looking up name="endpoints.health.sensitive"
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?
This `<logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="WARN"/>` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Excluding jetty-jndi from the classpath did the trick for me

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
  <!-- see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4710 -->
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-jndi</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: what if your application is using jetty-jndi for some purpose? I can't be the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add to logback.xml the code

```
<logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="WARN"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Jetty source code looks that logging level for `jndi` needs to be modified:

`<logger name="jndi" level="WARN"/>`